# Fetch value from Azure Key Vault reference (Managed identity)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I am trying to fetch secret values from azure key vault in Azure App Service.
My App Service has a managed identity
In the Azure Key vault, this managed identity is added under 'Role assignments' as 'Key vault contributor'
Also access policies has been added in azure key vault to give 'Get' permission to the AppServices's managed identity
Now in my c# code, I am trying to get the value of the AppSetting element using the code
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings['something'];

In my azure app service, under app settings, I have added the a key with name 'something' and it has the value pointing to the reference of the Key Vault as below:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

Now I am able to retrieve the value from the appsettings, but instead of the actual value, it is pulling the output as `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/c96f02080254f109c51a1f1cdb1931)`

I am expecting the output to be value that I have set, not the keyvault reference string itself.

I am using .Net MVC 4.7 web app

Comment: You don't need to add any RBAC permissions by the way. Key Vault uses only Access policies to authorize requests for secrets etc.

Comment: Key Vault references currently only support system-assigned managed identities. User-assigned identities cannot be used. - are you using a system assigned one? there are several other things in this article that are crucial for this to work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i figured out that even using ConfiguraionManager.AppSettings["keyname"] also works fine. In my case, i had done everything as listed above , but had enabled "Slot Deployment" option in Connection string configuration in App Service. Once i enabled, now i am able to access my key vault secrets.

Comment: My answer is also right. And use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable do not need to enable slot deployment.

Answer (score 0):

As junnas said, you just add webapp's MSI in key vault Access policy.

1.Turn on webapp `System-assign` managed identity.

2.Add the identity into keyvault `Access policy` with secret `Get` permission.

3.Add the reference of the Key Vault into webapp Application settings.

4.Use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppsettingName");` to get the secret vaule.

Here is the output:

[image]